# Black Screen - Default Gluon Project

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I followed [Gluon Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=10&v=O8A3Zc4KrhI) to deploy JavaFX on Android. It ran successfully on desktop, however, I got a black screen when I ran it on my android device. I'm currently using Android 4.2. What do you think is the problem?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Run `adb logcat` on command line with your device connected, open the app, and then post the output so we can see the possible errors.

Comment: @JoséPereda, I saw your app 2048FX, it was awesome! Who could ever thought, that JavaFx is possible on Android platform. It was a nice scene!